# Flatlist Item Not Clickable Inside Modal

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-native-modal

In my react native app I have a modal

Inside this Modal I have a FlatList

```
<Modal animationType="slide" transparent={false} visible={this.state.typeVisible}>
            
     <View style={styles.modalView}>
           <View style={styles.modal_header}>
                <Text style={styles.modal_header_text}>Select Type</Text>
                <Ionicons name="ios-close" size={48} style={styles.modal_header_close} onPress={this.toggleType} />
           </View>

           <View style={styles.modal_list_container}>

             <FlatList
                  keyExtractor={item => item.key}
                  data={[{ key: "Call Out" }, { key: "Call" }, { key: "Delivery" }, { key: "Dealt By Caller" }]}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    //this.handleType(item.key)
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
                      onPress={() => alert("Working!!") }
                    >
                      <View>
                        <Text style={styles.modal_list_item}>{item.key}</Text>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                  )}
                />

          </View>
     </View>
</Modal>
```

On IOS each of the items in the FlatList are clickable and the onPress will trigger the "Working!!" alert.

However the onPress is not working on Android. If I take the Flatlist outside the Modal the onPress will trigger the alert fine.

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong in trying to get it working inside the Modal on Android?

Ps: I have also tried TouchableOpacity in place of TouchableWithoutFeedback but to no avail

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are importing TouchableOpacity (TouchableWithoutFeedback) from "react-native-gesture-handler"

I don't know why, but you need to import it from "react-native"

```
import { TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
```

Hope that would help

Comment: Excellent, thanks a million @Vitalik Tabaharnuk. That has solved it! I spent longer than I am willing to admit trying to figure out what was up! Thanks again